# Retrieving data from database with dropdown list PHP/MySQL/HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

what I'm trying to achieve is retrieving data from database with dropdown list.

I can get the name variable from database and I can show all the database elements with a table but I don't know how can I merge these two. I want to click a button and show the selected dropdown list item's all database elements/column data.

Here is the code that retrieves product names for dropdown list:

```
<?php

$mysqli = NEW MySQLi('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb');
$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT namepro FROM mytable");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>developer mode</title>
</head>
<body>

<select>
<?php
while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()){
  $dropdown = $rows['namepro'];
  echo "<option value='$dropdown'>$dropdown</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the code that shows all database elements:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>size</th>
</tr>
<?php

$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb");
$sql = "SELECT namepro, res FROM mytable";
$result = $conn -> query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<tr><td>". $row["namepro"]. "</td><td>". $row["res"]. "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
else{
    echo "0 result";
}

$conn ->close();



?>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

I want to click a button and show the selected dropdown list item's all database elements/column data. How can I achieve this?
Thank you.

Comment: *"I want to click a button and show the selected dropdown list item's all database elements/column data. How can I achieve this? "* With or without a page reload?

Comment: It can be one of them.

Comment: And stackoverflow search [dropdown list PHP/MySQL/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+dropdown+list+PHP%2FMySQL%2FHTML) didn't help you out?

Comment: The search did not help me since I already populated my dropdown list. I am trying to achieve with each click to the button, the selected dropdown list's data must shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jquery & ajax` to achieve above .whenever button is `click` your jquery `click` function will get executed ,which will get value of `select box` with `class="select"` and pass it to your `php` page , like below :

**Your button**:

```
<button type="button" class="btn">Click Me!</button>
 <div id="show"></div> // here data from respone will be display
```

**Jquery & Ajax**:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".btn").click(function () {
            var value= $(".select").val();//getting value of select box with class="select"
            $.ajax({
                url: 'yourphppage',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {value : value},//sending value to yourphppage
                     success:function(data){

                $("#show").html(data);//here response from server will be display
                }
              });
            });
         });
</script>
```

**Php code** :

```
 <?php
    $value=$_POST['value'];//getting value sent from ajax
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb");
    $sql = "SELECT namepro, res FROM mytable where namepro='".$value."'";//passing in query
    $result = $conn -> query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
         echo "<table>
      <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>size</th>
      </tr>";
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<tr><td>". $row["namepro"]. "</td><td>". $row["res"]. "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
    else{
        echo "0 result";
    }

    $conn ->close();



    ?>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm getting Notice: Undefined index: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\stack.php on line 2
0 result
And I didn't get the $value=$_POST['value']; part. I'm using all the code inside a php file such as stack.php and in url: 'yourphppage', I just wrote the dropdown.php which includes dropdown elements.

Comment: did you give `class=“select”` to your `select` box ? Also `$value=$_POST['value'];` <— this line will get value which is pass from ajax in `data field`

Comment: Yes I give class="select" to 
    <select>  but I am using all the code in a single php file except dropdown.php which retrieves product names for dropdown list and I wrote url: 'dropdown.php' maybe this is my problem.

Comment: `url` should of `php` page where your `table` is there and `<script>` should be on php page where your `select` box is there